# What is the fastest way to merge N unsorted arrays into 1 sorted array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, big-o

I'm having trouble merging N unsorted arrays into 1 sorted array in JavaScript.

I know I can quickly concat then sort, but efficiency is important here.

I have arrays I'm getting back from an api (I can't ensure they arrive sorted) that need to end up in 1 sorted array. My first instinct was to try and not reinvent the wheel and try to find a way to reliably sort these into an output array. I figured I would try to sort each one, and then take advantage of the algorithm on [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-k-sorted-arrays-set-2-different-sized-arrays/). This requires the arrays to be in sorted order, so I sort the arrays first individually

I haven't spent much time in C++, so I spent some time trying to reimplement this in JavaScript:

```js
const TinyQueue = require('tinyqueue'); // const Heap = require('heap');

//typedef pair<int, pair<int, int> > ppi; 
const pair = (val1, val2) => ({ first: val1, second: val2 });
const ppi = (val1, [val2a, val2b]) => pair(val1, pair(val2a, val2b));
//console.log(ppi('a', ['b', 'c'])) -> { first: 'a', second: { first: 'b', second: 'c' } }

// This function takes an array of arrays as an 
// argument and all arrays are assumed to be 
// sorted. It merges them together and prints 
// the final sorted output.  
function mergeKArrays(arr) {
  const output = [];
  queue = new TinyQueue();

  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) queue.push(ppi(arr[i][0], [i, 0]));

  while(queue.length) {
    let curr = queue.pop();
    // i ==> Array Number 
    // j ==> Index in the array number   
    let i = curr.second.first;   
    let j = curr.second.second;

    output.unshift(curr.first); 

    // The next element belongs to same array as current. 
    if (j + 1 < arr[i].length) queue.push(ppi( arr[i][j + 1], [ i, j + 1]));
  }

  return output;
}
// -- Test Data --
const unsortedArrays = [
  [12, 2, 6], 
  [9, 1], 
  [2000, 23, 34, 90]
];
const sortedArrays = unsortedArrays.map(array => array.sort((a,b) => a - b));

console.log(sortedArrays);
const mergedArr = mergeKArrays(sortedArrays);

console.log(mergedArr);
```

The [Geeks for Geeks algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-k-sorted-arrays-set-2-different-sized-arrays/). [This code shared on repl.it](https://repl.it/@JamesGelok/mergeKarray).

So the input is `[ [ 2, 6, 12 ], [ 1, 9 ], [ 23, 34, 90, 2000 ] ]`

Expected output is `[ 1, 2, 6, 9, 12, 23, 34, 90, 2000 ]`

Actual output is `[ 9, 2000, 1, 90, 12, 34, 6, 23, 2 ]`

What is going wrong here? If this worked, is there a more efficient way to merge N unsorted arrays into 1 sorted one?

Comment: `Merge Sort` does the same thing. divides the arrays into smaller arrays and sort each one out and then merge them. So sorting each one out with `nlog(n)` then merging separately will not be efficient than merging 'em all first then sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

V8 uses [Timsort](https://v8.dev/blog/array-sort#timsort), which takes advantage of natural runs. So, you can flat and sort:

```js
const unsortedArrays = [
  [12, 2, 6], 
  [9, 1], 
  [2000, 23, 34, 90]
];
const sorted = unsortedArrays.flat().sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.info(sorted);
```

Comment: I think you missed the sorting function there, but kudos for the flat method, didn't know it existed until now

Comment: (your) `sort` sorts by string (1, 11, 111, 2) and not by number.

Answer (score 0):

I would flatten the array first then sort

```
 let input = [ [ 2, 6, 12 ], [ 1, 9 ], [ 23, 34, 90, 2000 ] ];
 let output = input.reduce((complete, next) => complete.concat(next), []) // to flatten
      .sort((a,b) => a-b) //to sort
```

according to [this](https://blog.shovonhasan.com/time-space-complexity-of-array-sort-in-v8/) article for big arrays google's V8 engine uses Quicksort, which takes roughly **O(n.log(n))**

Comment: I think the blog is outdated. V8 used to use quick sort, but they only use timsort, last I heard.